# Form Closing help

Tags: c#

How can I call the button1_Click event in the form closing event so I don't have to copy and paste the code from button1_Click?

```
      public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //Yes or no message box to exit the application
       DialogResult Response;
       Response = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
       if (Response == DialogResult.Yes)

           // Exits the application
           Application.Exit();
   }

   public void xGameThemeComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string folder = Application.StartupPath;
       string theme = (string)xGameThemeComboBox.Items[xGameThemeComboBox.SelectedIndex];
       string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, theme + ".jpg");
       Image newImage = new Bitmap(path);
       if (this.BackgroundImage != null) this.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
       {
           this.BackgroundImage = newImage;
       }

   }

   private void xGameForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {
      // call button1_Click here 
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you really need to do:

```
      private bool ShowClose()
   {
       //Yes or no message box to exit the application
       DialogResult Response;
       Response = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
       return Response == DialogResult.Yes;
   }

      public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Close();
   }

private void xGameForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {
      e.Cancel = !ShowClose();
   }
```

Comment: -1: Would show the dialog twice (once for the button click, one for `Application.Exit`'s raising of the `FormClosing` event

Comment: @R. Bemrose: Application.Exit doesn't rise FormClosing as far as i remember.

Comment: Yes it does, I even quoted the documentation in my own answer, as well as linked to it.

Answer (score 1):

better to extract the code in the `button1_Click` event into a method, then call the method from both events.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the contents of the button method into it's own method and then call the method from both spots.

Answer (score 0):

```
button1_Click(null, null);
```

Comment: thanks but can you also tell me why the message box makes me hit yes twice now to close the form?

Answer (score 0):

You should not show the MessageBox at all in the button.

You can simply call `Application.Exit()` in the button, and the `FormClosing` event can show the confirmation message.

Answer (score 0):

[`Application.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx) raises the `FormClosing` event on all open forms:

> A `FormClosing` event is raised for
>   every form represented by the
>   `OpenForms` property. This event can be
>   canceled by setting the Cancel 
>   property of their `FormClosingEventArgs`
>   parameter to true.
>
> If one of more of the handlers cancels
>   the event, then `Exit` returns without
>   further action. Otherwise, a
>   `FormClosed` event is raised for every
>   open form, then all running message
>   loops and forms are closed.

I would rewrite it like this:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Exits the application
    Application.Exit();
}

private void xGameForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //Yes or no message box to exit the application
    DialogResult Response;
    Response = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
    if (Response == DialogResult.No)
    {
        // Cancel the close, prevents applications from exiting.
        e.Cancel = true;
    } else {
        Application.Exit();
    }

}
```

Comment: I did the rewrite but now nothing happens the form won't close

Comment: That's unusual.  I tested this code, and it works fine in a sample .NET 2.0 project in Visual Studio 2008 SP1 for me.

Comment: Oh, I should have asked this in my last comment: You did notice that the `Response ==` was flipped to check for `DialogResult.No` rather than `Yes`?

Comment: Well let me be exact it works on the button but not when clicking the x on the form. When I click the X to exit the app it just closes the form and doesn't exit the application.

Comment: Oh, OK.  Actually... I may need to check and see what happens when you adjust what a form's Parent property is set to.  Closing a form may also close all other forms that have it as a parent.  Having said that, calling Applcation.Exit within a form's FormClosing event may or may not call itself.  I need to check that, too.

Comment: I just checked, calling Application.Exit() within a FormClosing event does not call that FormClosing event again.  Adjusted answer to take that into account.